# Is $(\mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z}, + , \cdot)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, + , \cdot)$ is only a field if $n$ is a prime number.

What happens in case $n=1$? Is it still not a field? Because I think that the issue (with the inverses) does not occur for $n=1$, does it?

Comment: It has only one element $0$. So it is a not field, since it has no multiplicative group.

Comment: @Eclipse Sun: no, fields have at least two elements.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field if, and only if, $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes you're right.

Comment: @carmichael561 Are you sure that this is an condition? Does this come from the fact that you remove the zero under multiplication?

Comment: @carmichael561 Why do fields have to have two elements?

Comment: You might find this article interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of the field axioms [as listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Classic_definition):

> Additive and multiplicative identity: there exist two different elements $0$ and $1$ in $F$ such that [for all $a\in F$] $a + 0 = a$ and $a · 1 = a$.

$\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z$ doesn't satisfy this axiom because it doesn't have two different elements.

The convention that fields (and integral domains more generally) have at least two elements, or equivalently, that $0\neq 1$, is analogous to the convention of defining a prime number to not be $1$, and defining a prime ideal to not be the entire ring.  It avoids having to frequently make exceptions for the trivial case.